# obstacles are not detected in local costmap/ Map is not updating at all

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d, ros-noetic, global-costmap, local-costmap

So i am using a pre-build map in which i am trying to navigate a real robot. I've watched the tutorials in ROS-Wiki on how to configure  plugin layers/ general parameters etc.

Basically nothing works the way it says you should do. For example i placed the static layer above inflation layer to be able to see the actual inflated radius around obstacles.
I mean i didn't saw any documentation about which order you should place plugins in costmap yaml files . So i am definitely missing some more important parts .

But the biggest problem which i cant solve no matter how much I've tried is that, dynamic obstacles are not displayed with inflation around them and rolling window doesn't seem to appear at all (see image).

I really need your help guys i am running out of time .If anyone could help me , bellow are my yaml files (common_costmap, local_costmap, global_costmap, move_base.launch)
Let me know if you need anything else to upload. Thank you in advance

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0

plugins:
  - {name: static_layer,               type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: obstacle_layer,                type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}  
  - {name: inflation_layer,               type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 5.0

  
  plugins:
    - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer,          type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

footprint: [[ 0.1025,-0.15 ], [0.1025, 0.15], [-0.1025, 0.15],[-0.1025,0.025],[-0.165,0.025],[-0.165,-0.025],[-0.1025,-0.025] ,[-0.1025, -0.15]]
 

height: 4 #Height of costmap (m).
width: 4 #Width of costmap (m).
origin_x: 2 #X origin of the costmap relative to width (m).
origin_y: 2 #Y origin of the costmap relative to height (m).
resolution: 0.02 #Resolution of 1 pixel of the costmap, in meters
publish_frequency: 5.0 #Frequency to publish costmap to topic.
update_frequency: 5.0 #Costmap update frequency.
robot_base_frame : "base_link" #Robot base frame.
rolling_window: true #Whether costmap should roll with robot base frame.
track_unknown_space: false # If false, treats unknown space as free space, else as unknown space.
transform_tolerance: 1

inflation_layer :
 enabled: true
 cost_scaling_factor: 1000.0 
 inflation_radius: 0.05


obstacle_layer:
  enabled: true
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  raytrace_range: 3.5
  inflation_radius: 0.05

  combination_method: 1
  observasion sources: LASER
  LASER: {data_type: LaserScan,sensor_frame: base_scan , topic: scan, expected_update_rate: 10, 
  observation_persistence: 1.0, marking: true, clearing: true}


static_layer:
    enabled: true 
    map_topic: "/map"
    always_send_full_costmap: True
    
    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<launch>

  <!-- Arguments -->

  <arg name="cmd_vel_topic" default="cmd_vel" />
  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  

  <!-- move_base -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">

    <param name="global_planner" value="navfn/NavfnROS" />
    <param name="local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/>

    
    <!--planner params-->
    <rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/base_global_planner.yaml" command="load" />
    <!--Costmap common parameters-->
    <rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load"         ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"     />
<rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <!--move base params-->
    <rosparam file="$(find auto_nav)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="$(arg cmd_vel_topic)"/>
<remap from="odom" to="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

[image]